# How to change password using password_hash?

Tags: php, mysqli, change-password, password-hash

I've tried changing this php code into a password_hash when the user input his password if he wants to change it, but it will never match because the pssword stored in my database is hashed during register, so i need the old pw which he input to match with the hashed password on db which is not working.

I know I should use password_verify butI do not know which part of this code should I insert it?

```
<?php
  include 'session.php';
  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'alumni');
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
  extract($_POST);


  $user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

  $old_pwd=$_POST['old_password'];
  $pwd=$_POST['password'];
  $c_pwd=$_POST['confirm_pwd'];
  if($old_pwd!="" && $pwd!="" && $c_pwd!="") :


  if($pwd == $c_pwd) :
  if($pwd!=$old_pwd) :
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `alumni` WHERE `username`='$user_check' AND `password` ='$old_pwd'";
    $db_check=$db->query($sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($db_check);
  if($count==1) :
    $fetch=$db->query("UPDATE `alumni` SET `password` = '$pwd' WHERE `username`='$user_check'");
    $old_pwd=''; $pwd =''; $c_pwd = '';
    $msg_sucess = "Password successfully updated!";
  else:
    $error = "Old password is incorrect. Please try again.";
  endif;
  else :
    $error = "Old password and new password are the same. Please try again.";
  endif;
  else:
    $error = "New password and confirm password do not match.";
  endif;
  else :
    $error = "Please fill all the fields";
  endif;   
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: Forget to start session at top!! You need to add `session_start()` at top of your page!!

Comment: @Saty you mean ``session_start()``.

Comment: AHHH: my mistake @JannisM yes i mean that!! thanks

Comment: i just forgot to copy it, sorry. i edited it already, but my problem is still the same @Saty

Comment: You never hash the `$old_pwd` before using it in `$sql="SELECT * FROM \`alumni\` WHERE \`username\`='$user_check' AND \`password\` ='$old_pwd'";`.

Comment: yes sir, because i'm not sure how to do it? @Sean

Comment: Well, instead of doing `SELECT *`, you could select the `password`, ie. `$sql="SELECT \`password\`  FROM \`alumni\` WHERE \`username\`='$user_check'";`. Then, instead of using `if($count==1)`, you could just do `if(password_verify($old_pwd,$db_check->fetch()['password'])`

Comment: i will try that now! @Sean

Comment: tried it but i got a fatal error `Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch()` which refers to the line `if(password_verify($old_pwd,$db_check->fetch()['password'])):` @Sean

Comment: I forget that `mysqli->fetch()` requires a `->bind_result()`. Try [`->fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), ie. `if(password_verify($old_pwd,$db_check->fetch_assoc()['password'])):`

Comment: No error, but the message says that my old password is incorrect. I believe my old_pwd is not yet hashed? Should i hash it? @Sean

Answer (score 2):

I finally have it working! Thank you so much for helping, especially to Sir Sean! :D

I changed this:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM `alumni` WHERE `username`='$user_check' AND `password` ='$old_pwd'";
$db_check=$db->query($sql);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($db_check);

if($count==1) :
    $fetch=$db->query("UPDATE `alumni` SET `password` = '$pwd' WHERE `username`='$user_check'");
```

to this:

```
 $sql=("SELECT * FROM alumni WHERE username='$user_check'");
 $db_check=$db->query($sql);
 if(password_verify($old_pwd,$db_check->fetch_assoc()['password'])):
$fetch=$db->query("UPDATE `alumni` SET `password` = '$new_pw' WHERE username`='$user_check'");
```

And yeah, I added a new variable $new_pw

```
$new_pw = password_hash($c_pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

If you guys think I did it in a wrong way, please feel free to comment. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
<?php
  include 'session.php';
  session_start();
  $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'alumni');
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
  extract($_POST);


  $user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

  $old_pwd=$_POST['old_password'];
  $pwd=$_POST['password'];
  $c_pwd=$_POST['confirm_pwd'];
  if($old_pwd!="" && $pwd!="" && $c_pwd!="") :


  if($pwd == $c_pwd) :
  if($pwd!=$old_pwd) :
    $sql="SELECT * FROM `alumni` WHERE `username`='$user_check' AND `password` =PASSWORD($old_pwd)";
    $db_check=$db->query($sql);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($db_check);
  if($count==1) :
    $fetch=$db->query("UPDATE `alumni` SET `password` = PASSWORD($pwd) WHERE `username`='$user_check'");
    $old_pwd=''; $pwd =''; $c_pwd = '';
    $msg_sucess = "Password successfully updated!";
  else:
    $error = "Old password is incorrect. Please try again.";
  endif;
  else :
    $error = "Old password and new password are the same. Please try again.";
  endif;
  else:
    $error = "New password and confirm password do not match.";
  endif;
  else :
    $error = "Please fill all the fields";
  endif;   
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: The OP is using [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php), not `md5()`

Comment: [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)  is a PHP function, **not** a MySQL function, so it will not work in the query like that. So it either needs to be hashed before the query, ie. `$old_pwd=password_hash($_POST['old_password']);`, or you need to concatenate it, ie. `... SET \`password\` = ".password_hash($pwd)." ...`

Comment: where u seen that in my answer?

Comment: It looks like you changed `password_hash()` to `PASSWORD()` in your last edit, that I missed